# Flex 4 ComboBox stays open when filtered

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

EDITED for more info:

I have a Flex 4 app with an external ItemRenderer inside of a DataGroup for a repeating form.  The DataGroup dataprovider is an ArrayCollection (coll_sites).

In the documentParent I have a trio of comboBoxes (Status, Year, Area) that trigger a filter function that operates directly on coll_sites.

The itemRenderer has a series of textInputs and comboBoxes.  Three of these comboBoxes are tied to fields in coll_sites (again, Status, Year and Area) that are filtered by the aforementioned parentDocument comboBoxes.

The problem I am having is that in the itemRenderer when the field is one of the filtered ones, the itemRenderer ComboBox will not close.  If it's not filtered, there is no problem.  I have confirmed that the problem ComboBox updates the ArrayCollection appropriately, it just won't close unless another Item in the dropdown is selected.

Abbreviated Code:

Filter ComboBox (parentDocument):

```
<s:DropDownList id="cbo_filter_Year" x="156" y="36" dataProvider="{coll_YearList}" labelField="YEAR" prompt="Year" change="filter()"/>;
```

Filter function:

```
private functionfilter():void {
    coll_sites.filterFunction = filterSitesCollection;
    coll_sites.refresh();
}
private function filterSitesCollection(item:Object):Boolean{
    //I filter the Sites based on the selected combobox
    var isMatch:Boolean = true;
    if (cbo_filter_Year.selectedIndex != -1){ 
        //if we have a year selected 
        if (item.YEAR.toString() != cbo_filter_Year.selectedItem.YEAR.toString()){
        isMatch = false;
        }
    }
 return isMatch;
}
```

Call to ItemRenderer in parentDocument:

```
<s:DataGroup itemRenderer="site_renderer" dataProvider="{coll_sites}" x="10" y="100">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

ItemRenderer:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">
    <s:BorderContainer x="0" y="0" width="653" height="215" borderWeight="2">
        <s:Label text="Site ID" x="0" y="10"/>
        <s:Label text="{data.SITE_ID}" x="0" y="25"/>
        <s:Label text="Year" x="150" y="10"/>
        <s:ComboBox id="cbo_Year" x="150" y="25" dataProvider="{parentDocument.coll_ShortYearList}" labelField="YEAR" selectedItem="{data.YEAR}"  change="data.YEAR=cbo_Year.selectedItem.YEAR"/>
        <s:Label text="Status" x="300" y="10"/>
        <s:ComboBox id="cbo_Status" x="300" y="25" dataProvider="{parentDocument.coll_SiteStatus}" labelField="STATUS" selectedItem="{data.STATUS}" change="data.STATUS=cbo_Status.selectedItem.STATUS;"/>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

In the ItemRenderer code above, the ComboBox for STATUS works exactly as it should but YEAR stays open after changing.  In my full code, I have three such filtered fields and all three behave exactly the same.  The other six fields which are not filtered, close appropriately.

I know this has to be something simple but I am at a loss.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear what triggers the filtering; and if the ComboBox loses focus when this filtering occurs.  If the ComboBox doesn't lose focus, and nothing in the ComboBox is selected; or the down arrow isn't click; then there is no action that will close the drop down.

You can force the ComboBox to close with the [closeDropDown() method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/DropDownListBase.html#closeDropDown%28%29).

Comment: @Flextras 
I appreciate your rapid response!

I have confirmed that the troubles comboBoxes update the ArrayCollection when the selection is made.  They do not loose focus.  It's the exact opposite.  I can't get them to loose focus until I choose another option.

Let's say my Year is set to 1975 (as retrieved from the AC).  I open the comboBox to choose 2010.  The AC gets updated but the comboBox won't close until I click on a year that is not 2010.  It then closes as if though nothing happened.

I have tried `change="closeDropDown();"` to no avail.  It's like the change process stops early.

Comment: @KHenry I'm pretty sure that change only triggers when a new item is selected; it doesn't sound like that is the case here.  If I understand; you are not filtering the dataProvider of the drop down, but rather of something else.  You can listen for the collectionChange event of the collection you're filtering; and closeDropDown when that event fires.

Comment: @Flextras,
I am going to have to offer a mea culpa here for having wasted your time.  <br/>
Turns out the filter function isn't what is holding it open.  It's a function I am calling to determine if the field is enabled.  The function seems to work perfectly fine when used with a textInput box, but fails miserably with the comboBox.  <br/>
Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: @KHenry does that mean you solved the issue?  IF so, was the solution what I described or something completely different?   If the was the solution I described; then please select it as such.  There should be a "Check box" next to my answer somewhere that you can select.  If not; then you should write up an answer to your own question and select it as such.